# Viewport resolution changes by itself

Tags: javascript, css, height, width, viewport

The following code (extracted from a much bigger piece of code) is meant to track mobile orientation (portrait vs landscape) every 500ms, and maintain a 'main' div with proportions 1:2 in portrait or 2:1 in landscape, which occupies the full width of the screen (and as much height as needed).

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S5. I start in portrait, then I rotate to landscape, then back to portrait I get a **much higher** resolution!!!

If I remove the 'main' div from the html, and leave only the 'test' div, things seem to behave normally, i.e., same portrait and landscape resolutions all the time.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script>
var wid = 0, hig = 0, widPrev = 0, higPrev = 0;
function start() {
  wid = window.innerWidth; hig = window.innerHeight;
  if ((wid != widPrev) || (hig != higPrev)) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '(' + wid + ',' + hig + ') ';
    widPrev = wid; higPrev = hig;
    var id;
    id = document.getElementById('main'); if (id != null) {
      id.style.width = wid + 'px';
      id.style.height = ((wid <= hig) ? 2*wid : wid/2) + 'px';
    }
  }
  setTimeout(start, 500);
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="start();">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For as far I know you need to test the scrollWidth/scrollHeight to get the proper values. `inner` values can be inaccurate. Google `MDN scrollWidth`.

Comment: But I can also **see** the viewport resolution is suddenly getting higher, as the font of the test is getting smaller... It looks like the already-existing 'main' div somehow affects this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replying to a comment above, I realized what's happening... After I increase the width of the 'main' div in landscape mode, when I rotate the device, the already-existing wide div causes the viewport to adjust for it. My workaround: temporarily decrease the size of the 'main' div, something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script>
var wid = 0, hig = 0, widPrev = 0, higPrev = 0;
function start() {
  wid = window.innerWidth; hig = window.innerHeight;
  if ((wid != widPrev) || (hig != higPrev)) {
    document.getElementById('main').style.width = '0'; //temporary
    document.getElementById('main').style.height = '0'; //temporary
    wid = window.innerWidth; hig = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '(' + wid + ',' + hig + ') ';
    document.getElementById('main').style.width = wid + 'px';
    document.getElementById('main').style.height = ((wid <= hig) ? 2*wid : wid/2) + 'px';
    widPrev = wid; higPrev = hig;
  }
  setTimeout(start, 500);
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="start();">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'll be happy to hear whether I was right in my guessing and if this solution is good (and cross-browser for all new browsers).